# How to make deferred task in Java (AppEngine) to not repeat in case of failure?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I read google docs, but there is said about non deferred task only. There we create xml file with params and can specify retry count.

But I use deferred tasks:

```
public static class ExpensiveOperation implements DeferredTask
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    System.out.println("Doing an expensive operation...");
    // expensive operation to be backgrounded goes here
  }
}
```

and create it that way:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();         
queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withPayload(new ExpensiveOperation(/*different params*/)));
```

How to specify that I don't want it to be restarted in case of failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Java user, but I see this in [Interface DeferredTask](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/DeferredTask) which I *think* you may be able to use:

> Normal return from this method is considered success and will not
>   retry unless [`DeferredTaskContext.markForRetry()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/DeferredTaskContext.html#markForRetry--) is called.
>   Exceptions thrown from this method will indicate a failure and will be
>   processed as a retry attempt unless
>   [DeferredTaskContext.setDoNotRetry(boolean)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/DeferredTaskContext.html#setDoNotRetry-boolean-) was set to `true`.

Comment: There are cases where even if you call setDoNotRetry(true), it will still be retried although it will likely be very infrequent.  If, for example your instance is shut down (machine or process crash for instance), the task server will not get the "setDoNotRetry" signal and will assume it failed and run the retry logic.. You can also set the queue parameter task-retry-limit to 0 and no retry attempts will be made.